Direct Current through a Copper Tube - Magnetic Field Question
Passing direct current through a straight copper wire generates the familiar "nested" cylinders of magnetic field strength along the length of the wire, decreasing in strength with distance.
When you similarly pass direct current through a copper tube, the field outside the copper is similar to a copper wire.  But inside the tube, according to an FEA simulation a friend of mine did for me, has no field.
The applicable laws regarding distance away from the conductor suggest that the field strength should be stronger near the inner diameter of the tube, and weakest at the furthest point, the centerline axis along the length of the tube.
My very experienced friend suggested that everything just cancels out in the tube, but again, that doesn't explain why the simulation wouldn't show varying magnetic intensity from the inner diameter toward the centerline, as their fields would be interacting evenly at the centerline from all sides of the copper, but unevenly anywhere off-center.
This is NOT a question about passing magnets inside a copper tube!  It's about the nature of magnetic fields generated by current through such a copper tube.
Please understand that I know FEA is a great tool, but without a technical explanation for the FEA's result, it remains suspect as a corner case the simulator wasn't designed to cover.  I'm trying to learn the reason the FEA is correct, or what to probe to get to a new understanding.
Thanks in advance for your considered responses!

What law do you know for the B field of a wire?  Why not apply it to the tube?

Cancellation does occur everywhere within the tube. This can be seen easily by applying Ampere's law, or derived very explicitly using the Biot-Savart law. It's not a corner case FEA isn't equipped to handle. An analogous result is the zero E-field within the interior of a uniformly charged spherical shell.

You assume the magnetostatic case. In the dynamic case, EM waves can exist inside the tube.

@my2cts Frobenius has already provided such a derivation. This question is very clearly about "direct current", e.g. the magnetostatic case.

@Puk ‘Frobenius’ I misread your comment …

$\newcommand{\bl}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}} 
\newcommand{\e}{\bl=}
\newcommand{\p}{\bl+}
\newcommand{\m}{\bl-}
\newcommand{\mb}[1]{\mathbf {#1}}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal {#1}}
\newcommand{\mr}[1]{\mathrm {#1}}
\newcommand{\mf}[1]{\mathfrak{#1}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\bl>}
\newcommand{\les}{\bl<}
\newcommand{\greq}{\bl\ge}
\newcommand{\leseq}{\bl\le}
\newcommand{\il}[1]{$\:#1\:$}
\newcommand{\vf}{\varphi}
\newcommand{\vt}{\vartheta}
\newcommand{\vr}{\varrho}
\newcommand{\plr}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\blr}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\clr}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\vlr}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\newcommand{\Vlr}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\newcommand{\lara}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\lav}[1]{\left\langle#1\right|}
\newcommand{\vra}[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\lavra}[2]{\left\langle#1|#2\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\lavvra}[3]{\left\langle#1\right|#2\left|#3\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\vp}{\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}}
\newcommand{\Vp}[1]{\vphantom{#1}}
\newcommand{\hp}[1]{\hphantom{#1}} 
\newcommand{\tl}[1]{\tag{#1}\label{#1}}$
The magnetic field of a circular cylindrical copper tube of finite wall thickness and infinite height.
We make the following statement which is in agreement with OP's results :

Inside a copper tube of this kind there is no magnetic field whereas outside the tube the magnetic field is identical to that produced by a wire of infinite length on the center line of the cylinder, of infinitesimal diameter and by current $\:\mr I\:$ equal to that of the copper tube.

To prove above statement it's sufficient to prove the same for a circular cylindrical copper shell of infinitesimal wall thickness and infinite height. Then, considering that the circular cylindrical copper tube of finite wall thickness consists of a very large number of circular cylindrical shells of infinitesimal wall thickness, the proof is given because of superposition.
$\bl{=\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!=}$
$\bl\S\:$A. The magnetic field inside a circular cylindrical shell
In Figure-01 current $\:\mr I\:$ flows on the lateral surface parallel to generators. We consider that this current $\:\mr I\:$ is uniformly distributed on the circumference of the circle yielding rotational symmetry. The intersection of a central infinitesimal angle $\:\mr d\vf\:$ with the cylinder generates a wire of infinite length with infinitesimal current
\begin{equation}
\mr{dI}\e \dfrac{\mr I}{2\pi}\mr d\vf
\tl{A-01}    
\end{equation}
In turn the circular cylindrical shell would be considered as consisting of a large number of wires of this kind so that the magnetic field at a field point $\:\mr P\:$ could be determined by superposition.
As shown in Figure-02 for the infinitesimal magnetic field $\:\mr d\mb B\:$ produced on the field point $\:\mr P\:$ by the wire positioned at $\:\mr T\:$ we have
\begin{equation}
\mr d\mb B \e \dfrac{\mu_0\mr{dI}}{2\pi r}\plr{\p\sin\vt,\m\cos\vt\vp} \e \dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{4\pi^2 }\plr{\p\dfrac{\sin\vt}{r}{\mr d}\vf,\m\dfrac{\cos\vt}{r}{\rm d}\vf}
\tl{A-02}    
\end{equation}
so
\begin{align}
\mr {dB_x} & \e \hp\m\plr{\dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{4\pi^2}}\dfrac{\sin\vt}{r}\mr d\vf
\tl{A-03a}\\
\mr {dB_y} & \e \m\plr{\dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{4\pi^2}}\dfrac{\cos\vt}{r}\rm d\vf
\tl{A-03b}
\end{align}
and by integration
\begin{align}
\mr{B_x} & \e \hp\m\plr{\dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{4\pi^2}}\!\!\int\limits_{\vf\e 0}^{\vf\e 2\pi}\!\!\dfrac{\sin\vt}{r}\mr d\vf
\tl{A-04a}\\
\mr{B_y} & \e \m\plr{\dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{4\pi^2}}\!\!\int\limits_{\vf\e 0}^{\vf\e 2\pi}\!\!\dfrac{\cos\vt}{r}\mr d\vf
\tl{A-04b}
\end{align}
For the treatment of the above integrals we will use the following equations resulting from the geometry of the system
\begin{align}
R\cos\vf  &\e r\cos\vt \p b
\tl{A-05a}\\
R\sin\vf &\e r\sin\vt 
\tl{A-05b}\\
r^2 & \e R^2 \p b^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf
\tl{A-05c}\\
R^2 & \e\,\, r^2 \p b^2 \p 2r\,b\cos\vt
\tl{A-05d}
\end{align}
For the integrand in equation \eqref{A-04a} we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\dfrac{\sin\vt}{r}\mr d\vf \stackrel{\eqref{A-05b}}{\e\!\e\!\e}\dfrac{R\sin\vf}{r^2}\mr d\vf \stackrel{\eqref{A-05c}}{\e\!\e\!\e}\m \dfrac{R}{R^2 \p b^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf}\mr d\cos\vf \e \\
&\dfrac{1}{2b}\dfrac{\mr d \plr{R^2 \p b^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf}}{\plr{R^2 \p b^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf}}\e \dfrac{1}{2b}\mr d \, \ell\mr n{\plr{R^2 \p b^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf}}\e \\
& \dfrac{1}{2b}\mr d \, \ell\mr n{\plr{r^2 }}\e \dfrac{1}{b}\mr d \, \ell\mr n r \\
\end{split}
\nonumber   
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\sin\vt}{r}\mr d\vf \e \dfrac{1}{2b}\mr d\, \ell\mr n{\plr{R^2 \p b^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf}}\e \dfrac{1}{b}\mr d\,\ell\mr n\, r\:\:\Vp{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{c}{d}}}
\tl{A-06}   
\end{equation}
For the integrand in equation \eqref{A-04b} we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\dfrac{\cos\vt}{r}\mr d\vf \stackrel{\eqref{A-05d}}{\e\!\e\!\e}\dfrac{R^2 \m b^2 \m r^2}{2\,b\, r^2}\mr d\vf \e \dfrac{1}{2b} \plr{\dfrac{R^2 \m b^2}{r^2}\m 1}\mr d\vf  \stackrel{\eqref{A-05c}}{\e\!\e\!\e}\\
&\dfrac{1}{2b}\plr{\dfrac{R^2 \m b^2}{R^2 \p b^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf}\mr d\vf \m \mr d\vf}\\
\end{split}
\tl{A-07}    
\end{equation}
Note that
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{R^2 \m b^2}{R^2 \p b^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf}\mr d\vf \e \mr d \blr{2\, \arctan\plr{\dfrac{R\p b}{R\m b}\tan\dfrac{\vf}{2}}} 
\tl{A-08}    
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\cos\vt}{r}\mr d\vf \e \dfrac{1}{2b}\mr d \blr{2\, \arctan\plr{\dfrac{R\p b}{R\m b}\tan\dfrac{\vf}{2}}\m\vf}\:\:\Vp{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{c}{d}}}
\tl{A-09}   
\end{equation}
From equations \eqref{A-04a}, \eqref{A-06} for the $\:\mr{B_x}\:$ component we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mr{B_x} & \e \plr{\dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{4\pi^2}}\!\!\int\limits_{\vf\e 0}^{\vf\e 2\pi}\!\!\dfrac{\sin\vt}{r}\mr d\vf \\
& \e \plr{\dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{8\pi^2 b}} \left.\ell\mr n{\plr{R^2 \p b^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf}}\vp\right\vert_{\vf\e 0}^{\vf\e 2\pi}\e 0
\end{split}
\tl{A-10}    
\end{equation}
while from equations \eqref{A-04b}, \eqref{A-09} for the $\:\mr{B_y}\:$ component we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mr{B_y} & \e \m\plr{\dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{4\pi^2}}\!\!\int\limits_{\vf\e 0}^{\vf\e 2\pi}\!\!\dfrac{\cos\vt}{r}\mr d\vf \\
& \e \m\plr{\dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{8\pi^2 b}}\!\!\underbrace{\int\limits_{\vf\e 0}^{\vf\e 2\pi}\!\!\plr{\dfrac{R^2 \m b^2}{R^2 \p b^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf} \m 1}\mr d\vf}_{0}\\ 
& \e \m\plr{\dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{8\pi^2 b}} \underbrace{\blr{2\, \arctan\plr{\dfrac{R\p b}{R\m b}\tan\dfrac{\vf}{2}}\m\vf}_{\vf\e 0}^{\vf\e 2\pi}}_{0}\e 0
\end{split}
\tl{A-11}    
\end{equation}
So

There is no magnetic field inside a circular cylindrical shell :
\begin{equation}
\mb B \e \plr{\mr{B_x},\mr{B_y}\vp} \e \plr{0,0}\e \bl 0
\tl{A-12}   
\end{equation}

For the functions and integrals appearing in equation \eqref{A-11} see Figure-05.
$\bl{-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-}$
$\bl\S\:$B. The magnetic field outside a circular cylindrical shell
As shown in Figure-03 for the infinitesimal magnetic field $\:\mr d\mb B\:$ produced on the field point $\:\mr P\:$ by the wire positioned at $\:\mr T\:$ we have
\begin{equation}
\mr d\mb B \e \dfrac{\mu_0\mr{dI}}{2\pi r}\plr{\sin\vr,\cos\vr\vp} \e \dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{4\pi^2 }\plr{\dfrac{\sin\vr}{r}{\mr d}\vf,\dfrac{\cos\vr}{r}{\rm d}\vf}
\tl{B-01}    
\end{equation}
so
\begin{align}
\mr {dB_x} & \e \plr{\dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{4\pi^2}}\dfrac{\sin\vr}{r}\mr d\vf
\tl{B-02a}\\
\mr {dB_y} & \e \plr{\dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{4\pi^2}}\dfrac{\cos\vr}{r}\rm d\vf
\tl{B-02b}
\end{align}
and by integration
\begin{align}
\mr{B_x} & \e \plr{\dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{4\pi^2}}\!\!\int\limits_{\vf\e 0}^{\vf\e 2\pi}\!\!\dfrac{\sin\vr}{r}\mr d\vf
\tl{B-03a}\\
\mr{B_y} & \e \plr{\dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{4\pi^2}}\!\!\int\limits_{\vf\e 0}^{\vf\e 2\pi}\!\!\dfrac{\cos\vr}{r}\mr d\vf
\tl{B-03b}
\end{align}
For the treatment of the above integrals we will use the following equations resulting from the geometry of the system
\begin{align}
R\cos\vf  &\e b \m r\cos\vr
\tl{B-04a}\\
R\sin\vf &\e r\sin\vr 
\tl{B-04b}\\
r^2 & \e R^2 \p b^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf
\tl{B-04c}\\
R^2 & \e\,\, r^2 \p b^2 \m 2r\,b\cos\vr
\tl{B-04d}
\end{align}
For the integrand in equation \eqref{B-03a} we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\dfrac{\sin\vr}{r}\mr d\vf \stackrel{\eqref{B-04b}}{\e\!\e\!\e}\dfrac{R\sin\vf}{r^2}\mr d\vf \stackrel{\eqref{B-04c}}{\e\!\e\!\e}\m \dfrac{R}{R^2 \p b^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf}\mr d\cos\vf \e \\
&\dfrac{1}{2b}\dfrac{\mr d \plr{R^2 \p b^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf}}{\plr{R^2 \p b^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf}}\e \dfrac{1}{2b}\mr d \, \ell\mr n{\plr{R^2 \p b^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf}}\e \\
& \dfrac{1}{2b}\mr d \, \ell\mr n{\plr{r^2 }}\e \dfrac{1}{b}\mr d \, \ell\mr n r \\
\end{split}
\nonumber   
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\sin\vr}{r}\mr d\vf \e \dfrac{1}{2b}\mr d\, \ell\mr n{\plr{R^2 \p b^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf}}\e \dfrac{1}{b}\mr d\,\ell\mr n\, r\:\:\Vp{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{c}{d}}}
\tl{B-05}   
\end{equation}
For the integrand in equation \eqref{B-03b} we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\dfrac{\cos\vr}{r}\mr d\vf \stackrel{\eqref{B-04d}}{\e\!\e\!\e}\dfrac{r^2 \p b^2 \m R^2}{2\,b\, r^2}\mr d\vf \e \dfrac{1}{2b} \plr{1 \p \dfrac{b^2 \m R^2}{r^2}}\mr d\vf  \stackrel{\eqref{B-04c}}{\e\!\e\!\e}\\
&\dfrac{1}{2b}\plr{\mr d\vf \p \dfrac{b^2 \m R^2}{b^2 \p R^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf}\mr d\vf}\\
\end{split}
\tl{B-06}    
\end{equation}
Note that
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{b^2 \m R^2}{b^2 \p R^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf}\mr d\vf \e \mr d \blr{2\, \arctan\plr{\dfrac{b\p R}{b\m R}\tan\dfrac{\vf}{2}}} 
\tl{B-07}    
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\cos\vr}{r}\mr d\vf \e \dfrac{1}{2b}\mr d \blr{\vf \p 2\, \arctan\plr{\dfrac{b\p R}{b\m R}\tan\dfrac{\vf}{2}}}\:\:\Vp{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{c}{d}}}
\tl{B-08}   
\end{equation}
From equations \eqref{B-03a}, \eqref{B-05} for the $\:\mr{B_x}\:$ component we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mr{B_x} & \e \plr{\dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{4\pi^2}}\!\!\int\limits_{\vf\e 0}^{\vf\e 2\pi}\!\!\dfrac{\sin\vr}{r}\mr d\vf \\
& \e \plr{\dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{8\pi^2 b}} \left.\ell\mr n{\plr{R^2 \p b^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf}}\vp\right\vert_{\vf\e 0}^{\vf\e 2\pi}\e 0
\end{split}
\tl{B-09}    
\end{equation}
while from equations \eqref{B-03b}, \eqref{B-08} for the $\:\mr{B_y}\:$ component we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mr{B_y} & \e \plr{\dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{4\pi^2}}\!\!\int\limits_{\vf\e 0}^{\vf\e 2\pi}\!\!\dfrac{\cos\vr}{r}\mr d\vf\\ 
& \e \plr{\dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{8\pi^2 b}} \!\!\underbrace{\int\limits_{\vf\e 0}^{\vf\e 2\pi}\!\!\plr{1 \p \dfrac{b^2 \m R^2}{b^2 \p R^2 \m 2R\,b\cos\vf}} \mr d\vf }_{4\pi}\\
&\e \plr{\dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{8\pi^2 b}} \underbrace{\blr{\vf \p 2\, \arctan\plr{\dfrac{b\p R}{b\m R}\tan\dfrac{\vf}{2}}}_{\vf\e 0}^{\vf\e 2\pi}}_{4\pi} \e \dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{2\pi b}
\end{split}
\tl{B-10}    
\end{equation}
From equations \eqref{B-09}, \eqref{B-10}

Outside a circular cylindrical shell the magnetic field is identical to that produced by a wire of infinite length on the center line of the cylinder, of infinitesimal diameter and by current $\:\mr I\:$ equal to that of the circular cylindrical shell :
\begin{equation}
\mb B \e \plr{\mr{B_x},\mr{B_y}\vp} \e \plr{0,\dfrac{\mu_0\rm I}{2\pi b}}
\tl{B-11}   
\end{equation}
as shown in Figure-04.

For the functions and integrals appearing in equation \eqref{B-10} see Figure-06.
$\bl{=\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!=}$







I am truly humbled by the depth of understanding you provided here.  I'm going to need to spend some time reviewing and thinking about this to get a full understanding, but everything is here!  I hope others benefit from the depth of your answer as well.  Thank you.

That there is no magnetic field inside a circular conducting tube due to a rotationally symmetric dc current flowing in it, follows directly from Maxwells equation in its integral form (Amperes law): The circular line integral of the magnetic field is equal to the surface integral of the enclosed current density and thus the total current enclosed by the loop (times the permeabiliy).  Inside the tube, there is no current enclosed, thus there is no magnetic field. See,e.g., Wikipedia: "Amperes Circuital Law"

Thank you freecharly for your considered response.  Mathematically I understand.  Logically the space outside of a conductor has no "current enclosed" either.  The magnetic field develops around the conductor.  The conductor wall is concave or convex (round OD or hollow ID), but it is still a conductor next to air/vacuum in both cases.  I understand that the math describes the empirical effects as both you and Frobenius have so kindly presented.  But does this mathematical representation of empirical evidence satisfy why?  I'm poking at the underpinnings...

@GravityTim If you take a closed line integral of B outside the conductor not circling it, you also have a zero value of the integral due to  compensating contribution of the varying B along the path. But in this asymmetric case,  Ampere's law cannot be used to determine B as opposed to a symmetric circular path around the axis outside or inside the hollow conductor. As Puk has commented above, it can be show with the Biot-Savart law  (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot–Savart_law) for all current filaments along the  tube that inside the tube their B contributions  add up to zero.
